# unable to terminate elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying so hard to delete an elastic beanstalk environment but it is showing some error as shown in the below screenshot. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is saying that something (else) is using the Security Group.

You should:

- Try to manually delete that Security Group
- If you get an error (most likely), then you will need to hunt for other resources that are using that security group (probably some other EC2 instances)
- If you are okay with removing the Security Group:

  - Detach the Security Group from the other resource(s)
  - Try terminating the stack again
- If you do *not* wish to delete that Security Group, then:

  - Delete the CloudFormation stack manually
  - When stack deletion fails, try it again and it will ask which resources you do *not* wish to delete. You can select the Security Group here
  - Once the Stack is deleted, go back into Elastic Beanstalk and try to clean things up